# how to create paging in a dynamic gridview

Tags: c#, gridview

I am using C# ,here i attach my partial code for dynamic grid view its working fine . I need to set paging on the dynamic grid view how can i call the OnPageIndexChanging

```
       GridView gv = new GridView();
        gv.AllowPaging = false;
        gv.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
        gv.GridLines = GridLines.Horizontal;
        gv.CellPadding = 2;
        gv.CellSpacing = 5;
        gv.HeaderStyle.BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        gv.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;

        gv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        BoundField nameColumn = new BoundField();
        nameColumn.DataField = "fld_id";
        nameColumn.HeaderText = "First Name";
        gv.Columns.Add(nameColumn);
        nameColumn = new BoundField();
        nameColumn.DataField = "fld_name";
        nameColumn.HeaderText = "Last Name";
        gv.Columns.Add(nameColumn);
        nameColumn = new BoundField();
        nameColumn.DataField = "fld_state";
        nameColumn.HeaderText = "Age";
        gv.Columns.Add(nameColumn);

        gv.DataSource = ds;

        gv.DataBind();
        plangrid.Controls.Add(gv);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
gv.AllowPaging = true;
gv.PageSize =10;
gv.PageIndexChanged+= new EventHandler(grid1_PageIndexChanged);

protected void grid1_PageIndexChanged(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
gv.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
gv.Databind();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
gv.AllowPaging = true;
gv.PageSize =10;
gv.PageIndexChanged+= new EventHandler(grid1_PageIndexChanging);

protected void grid1_PageIndexChanged(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
gv.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
gv.Databind();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set gw.AllowPaging = true;
Then set the gw.PageSize =   when  is the number of element that you want into your page.